# Битрикс: разные цены для разных пользователей

Tags: битрикс, users

Создал группу пользователей, создал тип цен, присвоил ценам пользователей. Вбил в настройках товара цену, присвоил своего пользователя нужной группе. Конечно же ничего не поменялось. Пытаюсь элементарно добраться до моей цены. Попробовал разные методы : CCatalogProduct и CPrice, CIBlockElement::GetList - не нахожу. Все способы выйти на цену возвращают базовую цену( как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * получаем цену товара со скидкой
 *
 * @param $productId
 * @param int $quantity
 * @param string $renewal
 * @return mixed
 */
function getProductPriceWithDiscount( $productId, $quantity = 1, $renewal = "N" ){

    global $USER;
    $arPrice = CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice($productId, $quantity, $USER->GetUserGroupArray(), $renewal);
    if (!$arPrice || count($arPrice) <= 0)
    {
        if ($nearestQuantity = CCatalogProduct::GetNearestQuantityPrice($productId, $quantity, $USER->GetUserGroupArray()))
        {
            $quantity = $nearestQuantity;
            $arPrice = CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice($productId, $quantity, $USER->GetUserGroupArray(), $renewal);
        }
    }

    return $arPrice;

}
```

попробуйте данную функцию использовать при получении цены на товар.
в функцию передаете ID товара и если нужно, другие опции.

Comment: Такая ситуация - есть несколько видов цен. Мне надо получить одну из них, при том что она не базовая.  Тоесть есть группа пользователей и цены к ним подвязаные. Мне надо получить конкретный вид цены для конкретного вида пользователя. Этот код не вижу чем может помочь.

Comment: эмм, как бы `CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice($productId, $quantity, $USER->GetUserGroupArray(), $renewal);` получает массив цен, там есть проверка групп пользователя. Если ты сделал правильно с типами цен, то, цены подвязанные для группы будут отображаться. Еще, для пользователей группы "Администраторы" базовая цена будет всегда отображаться. Создай тестовый пользователь, обычного юзера добавь в свою созданную группу и протестируй.

Comment: А можно как-то получить все цены? Я хочу увидеть массив

Comment: вот вам [ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/cprice/cprice__getlist.8f7c2a3e.php) на документацию

Comment: Это уже пробовал

Comment: Ваша функция возвращает массив, но в нем нет цены, только айди товара  [PRICE] => Array ( [ID] => 544978 [CATALOG_GROUP_ID] => 1 [PRICE] => [CURRENCY] => [ELEMENT_IBLOCK_ID] => 544978 [VAT_INCLUDED] => Y ) [DISCOUNT] => Array ( [VALUE] => [CURRENCY] => [MODULE_ID] => catalog ) [DISCOUNT_LIST] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [VALUE] => [CURRENCY] => [MODULE_ID] => catalog ) ) [RESULT_PRICE] => Array ( ) [PRODUCT_ID] => 544978 , и аналогичную я уже видел в самом битриксе/ в вызов передаю только айди товара

Comment: я понял что цена в [minimal_price][value] но скидка ее не меняет! При том, скидка отображается, но в корзину идет валью